# Touch screen L&F

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, gesture

I would like to do a specialized L&F for touch screens that take care of mouse gestures and size of controls.
I have never done a L&F before, so I'm looking for advices and if possible some tutorials to get me started.
Is there a look and feel that I could extend to ease the work?

---

I don't have much choice about using something else than java.  But java is used in touchscreen application.  What look and feel developpers use, to ease the work of developping touchscreen application in swing ?

Comment: I don't have much choice about using something else than java.  But java is used in touchscreen application.  What look and feel developpers use, to ease the work of developping touchscreen application in swing ?

Comment: I searched all over Internet and I got this one: Java multi-touch desktop framework http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AWT (and thus Swing) does not give us enough events - there are mouse-clicks, mouse-moves, and mouse-drags, but nothing like two- or more-finger movements which are used in modern touch applications.

I think there might be some vendor-specific APIs to do that, but I don't know anything about them.

Comment: Take a look at Multitouch for Java: http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page